Replacement for cmake j flag
How can I resolve the below error ?
cd /workspace/percona_mysql/xtrabackup/percona-xtrabackup-2.4.20 && \
    cmake -j 8,--parallel 8 . -DWITH_BOOST=$P/include \
        -DLIBEV_INCLUDE_DIRS=/workspace/dart_percona_57/xtrabackup/libev/include \
        -DLIBEV_LIB=/workspace/percona_mysql/xtrabackup/libev/lib/libev.a \
        -DWITH_MAN_PAGES=OFF \
        -DBUILD_CONFIG=xtrabackup_release \
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/a/percona_mysql/xtrabackup 
CMake Error: Unknown argument -j
CMake Error: Run 'cmake --help' for all supported options

cmake was working fine in earlier OS version alsi11 but failing with new os upgrade alsi22. What is the replacement that I can use instead of -j flag. Or how can I modify the above cmake command to have it running as it was earlier.
Thanks

The -j or --parallel option works only with the --build option. When configuring, you don't specify it. See CMake doc. Specifying both -j and --parallel does not make sense, the comma between them much less so.
